# Fantasy book I read in the army between 1986 and 1990

Tags: story-identification, books

1. Main character is a monk, mage and swordmaster who has just completed his testing. He has distant hereditary lines to a foreign nation of great wealth and an even greater history of violence, magic, and lewd civil behavior. He is sent there by his masters to "watch" the society.
2. The city where he is sent is full of debauchery, executions, slaves, cloning, sex slaves, genetic mutations of human and animals.
3. One of the main enemies is a rich mage who gorges on the flesh of humans and has a spell cast on himself that maintains a normal mans size, though he is massively obese without it.
4. The society uses slaves for all manner of things to include being fed upon by blood eating plants that produce foodstuffs for the society.
5. At the end of the book our hero is so overcome by the lifestyles of the people that he converses with the demon who gave the enemy the spell to keep him small, and uses it against him in combat to make him explode from his "overeating" of manflesh. This is totally against the rules of his monastery.
6. One particular scene that might remind someone who reads this of the books name is as follows.... A minion of the arch villain is coaxed into a bottle of purple worms, who while eating him will allow the minion great pleasure, however, the arch villain has tricked the minion and upon entering the bottle and being consumed, he is subjected to great amounts of pain and suffering.

Comment: I see you've posted it elsewhere. https://www.sffchronicles.com/threads/582488/

Answer (score 10):

I think this could be one of Mark E. Roger's novels. Most likely [Zorachus](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/495905.Zorachus) (1986) or its follow-up [The Nightmare of God](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/395385.The_Nightmare_of_God) (1988).

[image: Zorachus1][image: Zorachus2]

It follows an ascetic wizard-monk character named Zorachus as he travels to Khymir, a decadent city that runs of cruelty and twisted science/magic. This is an incredibly dark and grim bit of fantasy with a ton of body horror and debauchery. A lot of cannibalism, slavery, torture, and murder.

The scene with the purple worms is there. On page 131 of the mass market paperback, a character reveals a bottle and says, "There are worms in this, brought from another plane... I'm going to let them feed on me but I'll feel no pain; their saliva's a powerful drug. My Lord tells me it brings incredibly ecstacy." The bottle and worms enlarge via magic, he crawls into the bottle, and is then killed painfully.

Comment: Try as I might I cannot find a copy of this book (well, not at a sensible price). Can anyone confirm this is the book e.g. does it have the "purple worms" scene? If so I'll award the bounty.

Comment: I can confirm that this is the book. I flipped the pages of my copy and found the worm scene. On page 131 of the mass market paperback, a character reveals a bottle and says, "There are worms in this, brought from another plane... I'm going to let them feed on me but I'll feel no pain; their saliva's a powerful drug. My Lord tells me it brings incredibly ecstacy..." The bottle and worms enlarge via magic, he crawls into the bottle, and is then killed painfully.

Comment: Thanks, the bounty is yours! That was a great find - it's such an obscure book! I've added the stuff about the worms to your answer. I hope that's OK.